Nuxt3 dynamic <component>
can someone help me with creating a dynamic component based on JSON data in NUXT3.
I have DataTable body component like this:
<tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200">
          <tr v-for="item in data" :key="item._id">
            <td v-for="column in columns" class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
              <div v-if="column.definition">
                <component :is="resolveComponent(column?.definition(item[column.key]).component)" v-bind="column?.definition(item[column.key]).component.props" >
                  {{ column?.definition(item[column.key]).slot }}
                </component>
              </div>
              <div v-else>{{ item[column.key] }}</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

As you can see I want to render a component, where the :is prop is defined in column?.definition(item[column.key]).component
The definition function return an object and the .component property contains a simple string, as you can see here
{title: 'Email', key: 'email', definition: (item)=>{return {component: 'GeneralButton', props: {to: item._id}, slot: item}}}
So the result in this exmaple, which should be rendered is actualy:
<component :is="resolveComponent('GeneralButton')" ... >

And thats the problem, the resolveComponent doesnt work while I pass a variable in it. In case I pass there directly the same string, which is returned by definition function it works great.
I tried some other options, but none of them worked. The most used one is to use a global component, so the GeneralButton should be global. This aproach works, but I want to create a fully customisable component and I actualy dont know, which component will I want to use in future so this is not a good solution for me. (I saw also an advice to set all components as global and I want to avoid this cause of performance issues).
Other aproach was to override Nuxt3 auto import and manualy import desired component to DataTableBody component. This alse works and the resolveComponent() function than works with varibale :is, but it has the same problem as the previous one, I dont know which component I will get in definition() function. This should Actualy work, if there was a way to define the import dynamicly based on variable, but I am quite sure it is no possible, something like:
import {`$componentToRender`} from '#components' //This does not work and I didnt find any solution which works

Is there actualy a way to do this? Thanks :)

You cannot pass a variable to the resolveComponent() method.
<template>
  <component :is="resolveComponent(aVariableThatHoldsComponentName)" />
  This is Not OK ❌

  <component :is="resolveComponent('MyComponent')" />
  This is OK ✅

  <component :is="conditionalComponent" />
  This is OK ✅

  <component :is="getComponent(key)" />
  This is OK ✅
</template>

<script setup>
  const aVariableThatHoldsComponentName = 'MyComponent';

  const conditionalComponent = computed(() => {
    return condition ? resolveComponent('ComponentA') : resolveComponent('ComponentB')
  })

  const componentMap = {
      key1: resolveComponent('MyComponentA'),
      key2: resolveComponent('MyComponentB'),
      key3: resolveComponent('MyComponentC'),
  }
  const getComponent = (key) => {
    return componentMap[key]
  }
  const key = "key2";
</script>

However if your component is global (ex: ~/components/global/MyComponentName.vue or ~/components/MyComponent.global.vue) you can use it like this:
<template>
  <component :is="aVariableThatHoldsComponentName" />
  This is OK ✅
</template>

Please note that you should only use global components if you are sure that it is needed because global components are imported in every page even if not used.
Source

Hi, thanks for response. All of these aproaches require to know which component I want to render, because I need to pass a literal string to resolveComponent, or I need to define object of components, or I need to know which component should I make global. For now I didnt find any other solution, which should be fully dynamic. I actualy kind of miss the point of resolveComponent + , because you always need to know and have hardcoded string of desired component and in that case I actualy dont see the benefit of these, there are better ways to deal with set of known components.

@Bartas139 Indeed it is not that easy to make a component dynamic and this is why: Under the hood nuxt will literally crawl your app and automatically import every component that is needed to render every page, this makes AutoImport possible and makes your app tidy (shaking unused components out).  When a  is found Nuxt needs to know what components need to be bundled into your app so it might be conditionally imported (dependening on your app logic).
But again, if a set of your components are dynamic you can always place them in /components/global
